# datatable symbols (greater, less than) in search/filter

Tags: datatables

Hello i would like to ask, im just looking on DataTables.net and its look good but i didnt find a possibility of filtering single columns with symbols. 
example:
filter textarea of version column: > 1.14
im sure its possible but i didnt find it in documentation ?:-)

I find this
http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html
thats exactly what im looking for but i cant use > or < in search textareas ?:-)

Comment: the only thing close to what you are looking for is this http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

Comment: thank you i read that, but its not what im looking for :-)

Comment: You could create a second input that was a drop down containing the various operator clauses, ><=, but i think it would only work server side

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old question but I had same problem and:
1) I add additional dropdown to select operator (< > =) 
2) Merge select and text values in Json array
3) Posting this array to server as column search value
4) On server side I parsed this and search...